# Как завершить тест в Cypress?

Tags: javascript

Тест, кликает на номер телефона и открывается "Связь с телефоном", тест ожидает в этот момент и в итоге падает, как сделать чтобы после клика тест сразу завершился?

```
it('click phone', () => {
cy.visit('/')
cy.get('#app > div > footer > div > a > span.app-footer__phone').click()

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Используйте телефон с Android со своего компьютера`... это как? о_0

Comment: это винда 11)))